# How to handle Rails 'render' method in RubyGem test case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I'm currently working on a gem that adds some functionality to ActionView dynamically:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
  include CustomFormBuilder::FormHelper
end
```

This form builder has a `custom_form_for` method that calls `render` in order to render a partial.

In practice, this works great.

However, I am attempting to add some rspec test cases to test the gem, and I keep getting:

```
undefined method 'render' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroup::CustomFormBuilderFormHelper::CustomFormFor
```

I assume it's because my `on_load` callback is never being hit, though I have tried to programaticaly call `ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:action_view)`, which also didn't work.

Full spec code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CustomFormBuilder::CustomFormHelper do
    describe 'custom_form_for' do 
        before do 
            @new_record = CustomFormBuilderSpecHelper::Record.new
        end

        it "should create custom submit button" do
            custom_form_for(@new_record) do |builder|
                builder.submit('Submit').should eq 'fail'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And spec_helper:

```
require 'action_view'
require 'active_model'
require 'custom_form_builder'

include CustomFormBuilder::CustomFormHelper

module CustomFormBuilderSpecHelper
    class Record
        include ActiveModel::Validations
        validates :name, presence: true, inclusion: {in: %w(Name1 Name2 Name3)}

    end 
end
```

Comment: Please show your spec, and also the exact error when you programatically call `ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:action_view)`

Comment: I didn't get an error when calling `ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:action_view)`, it just didn't fix anything. I've added my spec to the original question.

Comment: Okay. Well, I'm stumped so here's hoping someone else can help.